# setting and changing css for all users viewing the site

Tags: html, css, web

currently creating something that will alert users in the office when a specific user is busy and unable to answer the phone.

how can I go about making it so that when a user clicks "engaged" it updates the colour in the availability box to red on their screen and update it on others at the same time?

I have a working prototype however its using .vbs to change the CSS file (find and replace) so it is a HTA app and would prefer a html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a script that executes every 1-2 seconds on the page that calls a PHP to check on user availability in a database. If a condition is met in the PHP file's output, it toggles the red color.

You'll need AJAX, PHP, a form of database (MySQL, etc) and jQuery / JS knowledge.

Comment: thanks for the answer, cleared a few things up for me.
got a mysql database with values, just creating the php now.
Thanks again